# Greasemonkey script for changing a part of href

Tags: javascript, url, href

This is a website eg: `example.com`. In this website there are links like `linkshrink.net/a123=example.com`.

What I want to do is replace `/linkshrink.net/a123=` this part with "/", i.e. just a slash, which will remove that ad go direct to the link.

All I want to do is just find and replace certain text in "href" in the whole page, when the page is getting loaded each time.

Can I do this in Greasemonkey? I don't know if that's possible, as I have zero knowledge of scripting.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var links = document.links;
for( i=0; i<document.links.length; i++ )
{
    var pattern = /http:\/\/linkshrink.net\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*\=/;
    if(pattern.test(document.links[i].href) )
    {

        document.links[i].href = document.links[i].href.substr(document.links[i].href.indexOf("=")+1);
    }
}
```

My Link was `linkshrink.net/a123=example.com`
Now In my web page it shows `example.com` 
I was able to scrub linkshrink

Now i tried on other site, its not working: 
  `bc.vc/13123/example.com`

```
var links = document.links;
for( i=0; i<document.links.length; i++ )
{
    var pattern = /http:\/\/bc.vc\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*\=/;
    if(pattern.test(document.links[i].href) )
    {

        document.links[i].href = document.links[i].href.substr(document.links[i].href.indexOf("=")+1);
    }
}
```

Where did i go wrong in ( linkshrink link ends with "=" sign , however `bc.vc` ends with "/" , I tried changing = sign with / sign still wont work.
Any Ideas?

Comment: StackOverflow is here to answer questions, not to do your homework

Comment: LOL its not homework , its just some personal interest

Comment: You have misunderstood the previous comment. Stack Overflow is not a code provisioning service. Please do your research first, and attempt to solve the problem before asking.

Comment: there's two `/` in the example ... which one are you referring to

Comment: I have updated the question , I need some answers !!!!

Comment: I also need for sh.st/st

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for bc.vc

```
 var links = document.links;
 for( i=0; i<document.links.length; i++ )
 {
    var pattern = /http:\/\/bc.vc\/[a-zA-Z0-9]*\//;
    if(pattern.test(document.links[i].href) )
   {

    document.links[i].href = document.links[i].href.substr(19);}
   }
```

`http://bc.vc/12345/` = 19 units

19 stands for total length of link which I want to delete